# What are possible causes of missing .frm files in mysql?

Tags: mysql, ibdata

Recently I faced `General error: 1813 Tablespace for table (..) exists.` and the solution was to find and remove appropriate `.ibd` file of trouble-causing table. I wonder why that issue even happened. I mean why there was only the .ibd file (with the size of only 64K) without corresponding `.frm`. My current mysql setup has file per table on and ibd autoextend by 12M without limitation. I am using mysql 5.7.19.

In addition, that table often gets dropped and recreated. Thanks for any clues and suggestion.

Comment: Let's see the SQL for doing the drop & recreate.

Comment: @RickJames after removing the .ibd file I could not managed to reproduce it again